# How to find the SyntaxNode for a method Symbol in a CompilationUnit?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I've added a bunch of nodes to a compilation unit, and now I would like to look up the syntax node corresponding to a given symbol:

```
var compilation = Compilation.Create("HelloWorld")
    .AddSyntaxTrees(SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit("<some namespace>"));

ISymbol symbol =  // some arbitrary symbol, e.g. a method whose syntax node I had
    compilation.GlobalNamespace.GetNamespaceMembers().First();

SyntaxToken token = ???;   // how do I get the token for that symbol?
```

How do I get the token for that symbol?

#### Note:

My goal is to be able to get the method body for each method from it `MethodSymbol`.

Comment: I think you don't want a `SyntaxToken`, that represents the smallest unit in the syntax tree, like an identifier. I think you rather want something like `MethodDeclarationSyntax`, right?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `ISymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences`.

Comment: Hmm, is `FindToken` sublinear time? Because I'm hoping to do this for every symbol.

Comment: `FindToken` should be roughly logarithmic - in nodes with several children it uses a binary search based on the position to find the token.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't work -- there is no method named `Ancestors`. I think you meant `Parent.FirstAncestorOrSelf`?

Comment: Btw, Kevin: I don't notice a `DeclaringSyntaxNodes` property, and I have the June CTP (I assume that's CTP 2?). Are you sure it's in there?

Comment: Yes, Parent.FirstAncestorOrSelf is what I meant. (Internally we have an extension method on `SyntaxToken`).  Regarding `DeclaringSyntaxNodes`, it has been added **since** the June CTP, so you'll have to wait for the next one to use it.

Comment: Did `DeclaringSyntaxNodes` change to `DeclaringSyntaxReferences`, or is that CTP yet to come out?

Comment: It changed to `DeclaringSyntaxReferences`.