# How to walk through MethodSymbol's body?

Tags: c#, roslyn

From the global namespace, is possible to iterate through all namespaces:

```
foreach (NamespaceSymbol @namespace in globalNamespace.GetNamespaceMembers())
```

From each namespace, it is possible to iterate through their classes:

```
foreach (NamedTypeSymbol @class in @namespace.GetTypeMembers())
```

The same happens with classes and methods or fields:

```
foreach (Symbol member in @class.GetMembers())
```

Yet, I could not find any way to iterate through a method's statements. How can I keep traversing down the semantic tree?

Comment: For the syntax tree (not this question, but similar), the answer is to use a syntax walker: https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2014/07/26/learn-roslyn-now-part-4-csharpsyntaxwalker/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the SyntaxNode that was used to declare the symbol:
[How to find the SyntaxNode for a method Symbol in a CompilationUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428662/how-to-find-the-syntaxnode-for-a-method-symbol-in-a-compilationunit)

Then once you have the SyntaxNode (e.g. MethodDeclarationSyntax) you can walk it e.g. using DescendantNodes() or ChildNodesAndTokens.